# Working with images

Tags: php, image

**Is there some script (better if php), which can do some operations like?**

1. *resizing*
2. *reduce/increase lightness*
3. *change contrast*
4. *change quality*

Or some api's, which can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most things I use PHP's `imageXXXX()` functions; they're portable, and pretty much every PHP install I've come across has them available.

For more advanced needs, consider using ImageMagick or some other scriptable image processing; if it doesn't come with a PHP interface, or you cannot install the required extensions, you can always 'shell out'.

Also, caching the processed images is probably a good idea in most situations, unless the output is different every time.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use [ImageMagik](http://www.imagemagick.org/) for this kind of thing. When I used it, you were restricted to Perl. It seems that there are now two PHP interfaces to the API.

Comment: Plus, you can always call the executable directly from any language, even if the bindings aren't there (permissions provided).

Answer (score 0):

I used this one recently and it worked really well for me, http://pear.php.net/package/Image_Transform

Answer (score 0):

[Click on the Download, and Download a great php class for resizing and croping images, the simplest way!](http://fincha.com/blog/2010/08/12/tutorial-bilderbearbeitung-mit-php-classe-leicht-gemacht/)

[And english version](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=de&sl=de&tl=en&u=http://fincha.com/blog/2010/08/12/tutorial-bilderbearbeitung-mit-php-classe-leicht-gemacht/)